# Archey installs properly, but spits a runtime error

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, rpm

I installed the RPM listed [here](http://github.com/djmelik/archey/downloads) (`archey-0.2.6-6.noarch.rpm`) for Archey:

When I run it, I get the following output:

```
$ archey
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/bin/archey", line 290, in <module>
     func()
File "/usr/bin/archey", line 176, in distro_display
output('OS', distro)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'distro' referenced before assignment
```

I ask as a more general question (since this is not the first package that has thrown errors), is this due to the developers releasing code with errors in it, or something to do with my setup, or perhaps something entirely different?

Distro: RHEL 6.4
Kernel: Linux 2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64

Comment: How should we know? We can't read your mind or access your system, you need to give us some information. You have tagged this as Red Hat Enterprise, is that your distribution? Which version? Kernel version? Archie version? What kind of errors have other packages thrown? Which packages? Where did you find the RPM (there is no link in your question)? What is your hardware? 32 or 64 bit system?

Comment: Sorry,

Distro: RHEL 6.4
Kernal: x86_64 Linux 2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64
archey-0.2.6-6.noarch.rpm
https://github.com/djmelik/archey/downloads
64-bit system

I'm going to focus on this package for now befor worrying about other packages. What I meant in stating that it happens with other packages is is it a common thing for packages to throw errors that look like programming errors? (such as referencing a variable before it has been initialized)

Comment: So, first of all, no it is not common but it happens. Software has bugs. Now, you are running a _very_ old kernel which can mean older libraries and that various dependencies of newer software will not be met.